# PHP Get variable explode

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am using this code for explode and show GET variables. But I would like remove current query in the link:

My explode code:

```
$k = $_GET['sef'];
$s_explode = explode("-",$k);

foreach($s_explode as $q) {
  if($q==$s_explode[0]) {
echo '<a class="active" href="/category/'.$q.'">'.$s_explode[0].' <span class="dismiss">&times;</span></a>';
  } else {
echo '<a href="/category/'.$q.'">'.$q.' <span class="dismiss">&times;</span></a>';
  }
}
```

If I using GET

website.com/?sef=game-book-video

Print is:

```
<a class="active" href="/category/game">game</a>
<a href="/category/book">book</a>
<a href="/category/video">video</a>
```

I would like if I using GET

website.com/?sef=game-book-video

```
<a class="active" href="/category/book-video">game</a>
<a href="/category/game-video">book</a>
<a href="/category/book-game">video</a>
```

I hope I can explain good sorry for my bad English.

Comment: In this anchor link  ```<a href="/category/game-video">book</a>``` what is the relation between ```game-video``` & ```book``` ? Imean, how a program will know if anchor value is ```book``` then anchor address href part will be ```game-video``` ?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Please be clear with what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be like this:

```
$k         = $_GET['sef'];
$s_explode = explode("-", $k);
//game-book-video

foreach($s_explode as $i => $q) {
    $parts = $s_explode;

    if(($key = array_search($q, $parts)) !== false) {
        unset($parts[$key]);
    }

    $class = ($i == 0 ? "class='active'" : '');

    echo '<a ' . $class . ' href="/category/'.implode('-', $parts).'">'.$q.' <span class="dismiss">&times;</span></a>';
}
```